# getOffset() of a packet returns 0 on the receiver's end

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I have a lengthy text file that I am trying to transport across UDP on localhost so naturally I have to break up the byte buffer to send the file in packets.

The problem I'm having is this:

On the server side, I send a packet of data with the offset into the byte buffer set to say 500:

```
        byte[] buf = text.getBytes();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, 500, BYTES_PER_PACKET, address, udp_port_num);

        System.out.println("Offset at server:  " + packet.getOffset());
        udpSocket.send(packet);
```

The print statement returns the expected answer of 500.

But then on the client side:

```
                byte[] buf = new byte[BYTES_PER_PACKET];                    
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, BYTES_PER_PACKET);

                udpSocket.receive(packet);

                String received = new String(packet.getData());

                System.out.println(received);
                System.out.println("Offset:  " + packet.getOffset());
```

It prints the correct text from the offset of the file in received, but packet.getOffset() always returns 0.  Why isn't it returning the same 500 from the server and/or how can I get it to return the same 500 from the server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of all this is:

1. At the sender you created a `DatagramPacket` using bytes 500..BYTES_PER_PACKET-500 of the source array.
2. You sent the packet. It went over the wire as a UDP datagram. It arrived as a UDP datagram.
3. At the receiver, you constructed a new byte array, and constructed a new `DatagramPacket` around it, specifying offset = 0, or no offset parameter. You received into the `DatagramPacket.` Java put the UDP datagram into the byte array in the `DatagramPacket,` starting at the offset you specified: zero.

Note that the sender's `DatagramPacket` did not itself go over the wire, nor the sender's byte array either.